# What is the fastest way to SELECT many colums from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select 25 columns from a database, with a conditions WHERE and ORDER BY.

I tried to make an index for that but it is limited to 16 columns only. How could I organize the mysql statements and database for the fastest way to select these 25 columns from the database within PHP?

Example Table:

Columns: A, B, C, D, E, F, ....

Query: "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, ... FROM table WHERE X = 5 ORDER BY Z"

UPDATE 1:

It is a large table (many rows) that's why I need an index to speed up the process.

Comment: ORDER BY is __not__ a condition.... the bits that appear in the WHERE clause are conditions. Create multiple indexes against each individual column, or restructure your table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indexes do not have a performance inpact in relation to the number of columns you select (excluding FULLTEXT). They are only used to speed when you use selection (WHERE) and sometimes ordering (ORDER BY) and agregation (GROUP BY etc.).

In this case you will need to define indexes on X and Z for optimal efficiency. Because MySQL can only use 1 index per query you'll need an index on (X,Z) (because selection on X is first, then ordering on Z). *Note that this doubles as an index for X*.

Also, an index containing *all* columns is almost the same as a table entry (albeit sorted) so you won't get much SELECT performance improvement from it, while INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE performance would plummet.

Comment: I learned that if you don't put the columns that you want to select in the index, you get point queries which are slow. If I make only an index on X and Z wouldn't I get a lot of point queries which slow down the process?

Comment: Incorrect. The way indices work is that they store the relevant information and a reference to the location of the row. Getting additional columns from a row is thus a trivial operations. Although it is true that it would be slightly faster if the row lookup wasn't neccesairy the performance gain is very, *very* minimal and doesn't even begin to outweight the other disadvantages (speed of modifying operations, size of the table etc.). You should read about them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index

Comment: The only time this might be sustifiable is when a specific combination of columns is frequently used, but even then I would advise against it as it is not the purpose of indices.

Comment: I got it from this tutorial, the guy is claiming that point queries are very very slow... (time: 14:44): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVNjqgf7zNw

Comment: @BastiaanWW That is not a tutorial, that is a talk about some advanced quering and optimization techniques. Your question indicates that you should bother yourself with that kind of thing just yet and first understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

What about a view with the mentioned columns and performing the select statement on this?

Comment: How do you mean a view with the mentioned columns?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the only index that will help is an index on both x and z. Alter table tbl add key (x, z).

mysql only uses 1 index per table per query. so having many indexes will not help for this one query.

Answer (score -1):

did you mean use     SELECT * FROM table where bla bla bla ?